# Is it possible to do an "inline" insertion of text with ex

Tags: ex-mode

So I'm reading the [ex spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ex.html) and came across the following section under Command Line Parsing in ex:

> 12. Otherwise:
>
>     a. If the command was a map, unmap, abbreviate, or unabbreviate command, characters up to the first non-`<control>-V`-escaped `<newline>`, `<vertical-line>`, or double-quote character shall be skipped and be part of the command.
>
>     b. Otherwise, characters up to the first non-`<backslash>`-escaped `<newline>`, `<vertical-line>`, or double-quote character shall be skipped and be part of the command.
>
>     c. If the command was an append, change, or insert command, and the step 12.b. ended at a `<vertical-line>` character, any subsequent characters, up to the next non-`<backslash>`-escaped `<newline>` shall be used as input text to the command.
>
> ...

To me, this meant that the command

```
:i | quit
```

would insert the word "quit" instead of potentially exiting when I exit text input mode. Is this a bug or am I misreading the spec?

The `ex` command on my machine is symlinked to vim (version 8.2)

Comment: I would tend to agree with your interpretation but I would find the described behavior weird.

Comment: I guess it would be weird considering similar functionality with other apps like here docs. It felt strange to me since I originally expected the command and text to be on the same line. ie having `:i here` insert the a line containing "here" instead of throwing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying the spec, I think i found clarity

> Append
>
> ```
>   Historically, any text following a <vertical-line> command
>   separator after an append, change, or insert command became part
>   of the insert text. For example, in the command:
>
>       :g/pattern/append|stuff1
>
>   a line containing the text "stuff1" would be appended to each
>   line matching pattern.
> ```

So it seems pretty clear how the "|" should be handled and it seems like my ex implementation (vim) is buggy. Contrary to my initial thought, the command would still have to be ended with `.\n`